# People percentage probability problem

Tags: probability

I’m struggling to solve a probability problem meant for children, and this is driving me crazy.

The text of the problem is the following:

> In a group of people there are $62\%$ of men and $38\%$ of women. If we pick $2$ people at random what is the probability that we pick a man and a woman?

What is blocking me is the fact that we don’t know the total number of people.

How can we formally prove that the answer is $24\%$?

Comment: It often happens in problems like this that you meant to assume that the total number is so large that you can assume each choice is independent of any other.

Comment: Note:  to justify that answer I think you are also meant to assume that you get a man and a woman $\textit {in that order}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right to raise that issue, though there is another in that the binomial probability is about $0.47$

Here is one possible rationalisation if you assume the $0.62$ and $0.38$ are precise and the $0.24$ is rounded

- If there was an almost infinite population then the probability of picking a man and then a woman (not the reverse order) would be $0.62 \times 0.38 = 0.2356$ which rounds to $0.24$
- If there were $n$ people then the hypergeometric probability of picking a man and then a woman would be $\frac{0.62n \times 0.38n}{n \times (n-1)} = \frac{0.2356}{1-\frac1n}$.  But you need $n\ge 50$ to get precisely $0.62$ and $0.38$ and so the probability is no more than $\frac{0.2356}{1-\frac1{50}} \approx 0.24041$ and no less than than $0.2356$.  So the answer rounds to $0.24$ in any case.